# Update after Insert not working sometimes

Tags: sql-server

I have procedure that inserts data into a table A and then updates another table B.

After passing values to the procedure, insert seems to be working fine, but update doesn't work sometimes.

`INSERT INTO A (a, b, c) VALUES (@v_a, @v_b, @v_c) 
 ...
 UPDATE B SET status = '02' WHERE a = @v_a, b = @v_b`

`@v_a, @v_b, @v_c` are values that procedure gets from my code.

The code looks similar as above. When I check table A, it inserts correct data, and B it has data that's true `WHERE a = @v_a, b = @v_b`.

But sometimes `UPDATE` doesn't work.

Is my code just wrong? or did anyone have the same problem?

Edit : 
I was just sketching out so made a mistake. The code is
`UPDATE B SET status = '02' WHERE a = @v_a AND b = @v_b` So there is no syntax error. I guess I'll need to parse it through once again.

Thank you for all the replies though.

Comment: change to `WHERE a = @v_a AND b = @v_b`

Comment: I'm shocked you didn't get a syntax error.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a debug bit parameter to your sproc, and adding queries inside of "IF @debug = 1" statements to help you debug what's wrong. Without having access to your sproc / data, no one can have a for sure answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your comma separating the variables to AND:

```
UPDATE B SET status = '02' WHERE a = @v_a AND b = @v_b;
```

Or OR:

```
UPDATE B SET status = '02' WHERE a = @v_a OR b = @v_b;
```